# ¿Cómo saber si un string es alfanumérico con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo, tengo la cadena `11aa32bbb5` y quiero extraer solo los caracteres `aa`, `bbb` o los números `11, 32, 5`

¿Cómo confirmo que una letra o string sea alfanumérico o no?

Esto es la implementación que tengo.

```
const checkChar = (ch) => {
    if (ch.charCodeAt(0) >= 97 && ch.charCodeAt(0) <= 122) {
        return true;
    };
    return false;
};
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: Tengo una respuesta que puede solucionar la duda, pero ¿Qué has intentado específicamente?

Comment: He intentado a hacer un loop y confirmar que el carácter está entre o fuera de 97 y 122 con `charCodeAt()`

Comment: Genial, añade el código que tengas para poderte ayudar

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, añadí mi código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión regular, de la siguiente manera

```js
const filterAlpha = (str) => {
  if (typeof str !== "string") return false;
  return str.replace(/[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]/g, "") === "";
}

console.log(filterAlpha("aabsbfsf"));
console.log(filterAlpha("xfdsdt32652aFDFGñ34532524"));
console.log(filterAlpha("adfasdgfesdgrdfñ25325tADDSG"));
console.log(filterAlpha("11aa32bbb5"));
```

Reemplazamos tanto de la A a la Z y todos los números del string, de manera que si resulta vacío, lógicamente será alfanumérico

Combinamos 3 expresiones regulares:

```
[A-Z]
[a-z]
[0-0]
```

De manera que contamos del 0 al 9 por cada número en el string, además de las letras de la A a la Z en mayúsculas y minúsculas, usaremos el operador */g* para indicar que vamos a reemplazar todas las coincidencias existentes, si quisiéramos extraer solo la primera coincidencias sería de la siguiente manera

```
/[a-z-0-9]/i
```

De manera que el operador */i* indica **ignore case**, es decir que **no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas**

---

Para extraer las coincidencias podemos usar `.match`

```js
console.log("243adfsdf25edh".match(/[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]/g));
console.log("ñ".match(/[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]/g));
console.log("ñ1abc".match(/[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]/g));
```

Comment: Genial! Tengo que aprender REGEX pero esto es lo que necesito.